# Limit number of messages sent by Exchange 2007

Tags: email, exchange

I have a Exchange 2007, it's possible to limit the number of messages sent by a user?
When a computer is infected by virus or similar, this user sends a lot of emails (about 100.000 emails in a day). If it's possible to limit, I can delete of queue.
Now when I have a issue of emails, domain automatically appears in black lists.
I search a lot of documentation, but I think Exchange 2007 don't have this capability.
Anyone knows how enable this function?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the virus/malware will not use your in house Exchange to send the email, most of them create a local SMTP service on the infected computer to send the mass email.

As such to limit the impact I would close the port 25 to anything except your Exchange's server IP.

I would use another public IP for the outgooing traffic on port 25, thus if a user bypass your firewall restriction somehow, your public IP, used for anything else than Exchange will be blacklisted, but not your Exchange IP.

For your actual question, you could adjust [client throttling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540454(v=exchg.80).aspx), or you could route your outgooing email to a smarthost that offer spam scanning.